# Nexus maven integration getting the below error

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin, nexus

I am using nexus-3.0.1-01 repository with maven 3. When I tried to build  the maven project I am getting the below error.

> Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of
>   its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact
>   descriptor for
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5: Failure to
>   find org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.5 in
>   http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/groups/public was cached in the
>   local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update
>   interval of nexus has elapsed or updates are forced.

Settings.xml

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
    <localRepository>C:\maven</localRepository>
    <!-- interactiveMode
   | This will determine whether maven prompts you when it needs input. If set to false,
   | maven will use a sensible default value, perhaps based on some other setting, for
   | the parameter in question.
   |
   | Default: true
  <interactiveMode>true</interactiveMode>
  -->
    <!-- offline
   | Determines whether maven should attempt to connect to the network when executing a build.
   | This will have an effect on artifact downloads, artifact deployment, and others.
   |
   | Default: false
  <offline>false</offline>
  -->
    <!-- pluginGroups
   | This is a list of additional group identifiers that will be searched when resolving plugins by their prefix, i.e.
   | when invoking a command line like "mvn prefix:goal". Maven will automatically add the group identifiers
   | "org.apache.maven.plugins" and "org.codehaus.mojo" if these are not already contained in the list.
   |-->
    <pluginGroups>
        <!-- pluginGroup
     | Specifies a further group identifier to use for plugin lookup.
    <pluginGroup>com.your.plugins</pluginGroup>
    -->
    </pluginGroups>
    <!-- proxies
   | This is a list of proxies which can be used on this machine to connect to the network.
   | Unless otherwise specified (by system property or command-line switch), the first proxy
   | specification in this list marked as active will be used.
   |-->
    <proxies>
        <!-- proxy
     | Specification for one proxy, to be used in connecting to the network.
     |
    <proxy>
      <id>optional</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <username>proxyuser</username>
      <password>proxypass</password>
      <host>proxy.host.net</host>
      <port>80</port>
      <nonProxyHosts>local.net|some.host.com</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
    -->
    </proxies>
    <!-- servers
   | This is a list of authentication profiles, keyed by the server-id used within the system.
   | Authentication profiles can be used whenever maven must make a connection to a remote server.
   |-->
    <servers>
        <!-- server
     | Specifies the authentication information to use when connecting to a particular server, identified by
     | a unique name within the system (referred to by the 'id' attribute below).
     |
     | NOTE: You should either specify username/password OR privateKey/passphrase, since these pairings are
     |       used together.
     |
    <server>
      <id>deploymentRepo</id>
      <username>repouser</username>
      <password>repopwd</password>
    </server>
    -->
        <!-- Another sample, using keys to authenticate.
    <server>
      <id>siteServer</id>
      <privateKey>/path/to/private/key</privateKey>
      <passphrase>optional; leave empty if not used.</passphrase>
    </server>
    -->
    </servers>
    <!-- mirrors
   | This is a list of mirrors to be used in downloading artifacts from remote repositories.
   |
   | It works like this: a POM may declare a repository to use in resolving certain artifacts.
   | However, this repository may have problems with heavy traffic at times, so people have mirrored
   | it to several places.
   |
   | That repository definition will have a unique id, so we can create a mirror reference for that
   | repository, to be used as an alternate download site. The mirror site will be the preferred
   | server for that repository.
   |-->
    <mirrors>
        <mirror>
            <!--This sends everything else to /public -->
            <id>nexus</id>
            <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
            <url>http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
        </mirror>
    </mirrors>
    <!-- profiles
   | This is a list of profiles which can be activated in a variety of ways, and which can modify
   | the build process. Profiles provided in the settings.xml are intended to provide local machine-
   | specific paths and repository locations which allow the build to work in the local environment.
   |
   | For example, if you have an integration testing plugin - like cactus - that needs to know where
   | your Tomcat instance is installed, you can provide a variable here such that the variable is
   | dereferenced during the build process to configure the cactus plugin.
   |
   | As noted above, profiles can be activated in a variety of ways. One way - the activeProfiles
   | section of this document (settings.xml) - will be discussed later. Another way essentially
   | relies on the detection of a system property, either matching a particular value for the property,
   | or merely testing its existence. Profiles can also be activated by JDK version prefix, where a
   | value of '1.4' might activate a profile when the build is executed on a JDK version of '1.4.2_07'.
   | Finally, the list of active profiles can be specified directly from the command line.
   |
   | NOTE: For profiles defined in the settings.xml, you are restricted to specifying only artifact
   |       repositories, plugin repositories, and free-form properties to be used as configuration
   |       variables for plugins in the POM.
   |
   |-->
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>nexus</id>
            <!--Enable snapshots for the built in central repo to direct -->
            <!--all requests to nexus via the mirror -->
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>central</id>
                    <url>http://central</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
            <pluginRepositories>
                <pluginRepository>
                    <id>central</id>
                    <url>http://central</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </pluginRepository>
            </pluginRepositories>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <activeProfiles>
        <!--make the profile active all the time -->
        <activeProfile>nexus</activeProfile>
    </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

Comment: has your local nexus access to maven central? is there anything in the logs of your nexus?

Comment: How do check that one whether  local nexus access to maven central. when I tried to run maven from command prompt I am getting the below error mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.graniteds.archetypes  -DarchetypeArtifactId=graniteds-tide-spring-jpa-hibernate  -DgroupId=org.example --------------
No plugin found for prefix 'archetype' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.sonatype.plugins, org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (C:\mavens), nexus (http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/groups/public)]

Comment: you check by looking into the nexus logs. verify that a build or command you run locally leads to requests against your nexus (that should be the case looking at your config, but please verify). Since the missing plugins are all pretty essential it looks that nexus cannot find them in the remote repositories. Either there are none configured or it cannot reach them. But that should be visible in the logs and the system feeds (unresolveable artifacts).

Comment: 127.0.0.1 - - [29/Aug/2016:01:14:19 +0530] "GET /nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/2.8/maven-dependency-plugin-2.8.jar HTTP/1.1" 404 1784 15
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Aug/2016:01:14:19 +0530] "GET /nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-release-plugin/2.3.2/maven-release-plugin-2.3.2.pom HTTP/1.1" 404 1784 0
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Aug/2016:01:14:20 +0530] "GET /nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-release-plugin/2.3.2/maven-release-plugin-2.3.2.jar HTTP/1.1" 404 1784 0

Comment: ok. that seems to be the access log. What proxy repositories are assigned in the group "public" in nexus? Nexus should attempt to resolve the plugins and dependencies that are not yet cached. If there are no proxy repositories assigned in the "public" group it will not do any lookups to maven central or other repositories. That should be visible in the other nexus logs as well.

Comment: I think it has maven-central,maven-releases,maven-snapshots

Comment: Proxy
Remote storage:
Location of the remote repository being proxied https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/

Comment: I have gone through the doc and done all the configuration properly. Still I am getting the same error. Please assist me.

Comment: have a look at the system feeds in nexus: /nexus/service/local/feeds/errorWarning and /nexus/service/local/feeds/recentlyCachedOrDeployedArtifacts (these urls are for version 2.13, they are available in the web ui as well). If nexus cannot cache or download artifacts there is something in the logs somewhere. Also if it works - in that case we need to check the maven settings again. But first make sure nexus can reach out to maven central.

Comment: Thanks, nexus is not reaching to maven central . I do not know why?

Comment: is there a company proxy you need to configure? or some other thing blocking the network connection? Later versions of Nexus switched to HTTPS connections towards Maven Central. Sometimes the keystore/truststore is modified inside companies.

Comment: No, I am using my personal system to connect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your settings.xml uses a wrong URL for the maven-public group. This URL changed from version 2 to version 3.

A correct example can be found in the [documentation](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/3.0/reference/maven.html#maven-sect-single-group) or the [example projects](https://github.com/sonatype/nexus-book-examples/blob/nexus-3.0.x/maven/settings/settings.xml).

Comment: I did not notice that. Really you have helped me a lot.I took over three days  searching error on google. Finally you notice the wrong url was being used.

Comment: I am doing nexus setup in my company system.I have configured the proxy but I am getting ntlm authentication  error. what does it mean?

Comment: Please ask on our mailing list or as a separate question on stackoverflow.